# Running time with while loop

Tags: runtime-analysis

What's the running time of:

```
foo(n)
if(n==1) return;
int i=1;
while(i<n)
{
    i=i+2
}
foo(n-2)
```

There are $n/2$ recursive calls to `foo` but how to add to the calculation the while loop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a system behind the magic of algorithm analysis?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the relation likes the following:
$$T(n) = T(n-2) + \frac{n}{2}$$
$$T(n) = \frac{n}{2} + \frac{n-2}{2} + \frac{n-4}{2}+\cdots +\frac{n-(n-2)}{2} = $$
$$\frac{n^2-2(1+2+3+\cdots+(\frac{n}{2}-1))}{2}=$$
$$\frac{n^2-(\frac{n}{2}-1)\times \frac{n}{2}}{2}= \Theta(n^2)$$

Answer (score 1):

The number of the iterations of the while loop is

$$n/2+(n-2)/2 + (n-4)/2 + \dots +1$$

which is $O(n^2)$.

Comment: What about the $n/2$ calls? so what's the total time?

Comment: We prefer detailed answers that come with explanation.  Where did that expression come from?  What's the rationale/justification for it?  What approach did you use to get that answer?